# When scheduling jobs to be run by crontab, should leading zeros be used for the hour?

Tags: cron, file-format

Let's assume that I want to run a shell script named `test.sh` at 1 AM every day. I could either use:

```
0 1 * * * /home/user/test.sh
```

Or I could use:

```
0 01 * * * /home/user/test.sh
```

For the above example, which is technically the correct answer - should a leading `0` be used in the shedule, or should just the number of the hour be entered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `cron` accepts zero-filled numbers, you may use them.

Since [the POSIX specification for `crontab`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/crontab.html) and the `crontab(5)` manual on all systems that I have access to only give examples *without* zero-filled numbers (without actually saying anything about the formatting of numbers), it may be prudent to stay with non-filled numbers if you at some point find yourself on a system where zero-filled numbers are not accepted.

There are examples of systems where `01` is the same as `*`, not `1`:

- [cron job for hour=7-19 runs every hour instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622441/cron-job-for-hour-7-19-runs-every-hour-instead)