# cron job for hour=7-19 runs every hour instead

Tags: cron

Here is the job, intended to run every 15 minutes between 7AM and 7PM:

```
*/15 07-19 * * * /home/max/bashScripts/rsyncMe >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The job is running every 15 minutes every hour instead, i.e., it runs from midnight to 23:45.

The job itself completes in under 5 minutes each time it is started.

The OS is Debian-Buster. Cron is up to date.

What might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Does it work without the leading 0, as `7-19`? Obviously it should work as 07-19, but I never saw an example with leading zeros, and I have a vague recollection this issue has been seen before. (Clutching at straws!)

Comment: Also this is helpful: https://crontab.guru/

Comment: A leading `0` often means "this is octal." I don't know if they use the standard C library to parse, but that _could_ be it...

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco, except that here the number is `07`, which is the same in octal and in decimal

Comment: it is parsed in entry.c, `get_list` → `get_range` → `get_number`, which ends up doing an [atoi](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man3/atoi.3.html). No reason this should fail...

Comment: @ilkkachu I am aware... so what is octal `19` then?

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco, an error :) But the standard routines (`strtol` etc) only parse one number, not a pair, so even if cron uses those, it'd have to split the string on the dash first, so it'd be left with `07` and `19`. Only the first has the zero-prefix.

Comment: FWIW, I can't reproduce this, at least not as a problem with the zero prefix. I got the same results for `0 01-04 * * *` and `0  1-4  * * *`, that is, it ran until 4:00, but not at 5:00. Also, all the versions of cron I looked at use `atoi` to parse the numbers, and that takes them as base-10:
https://salsa.debian.org/debian/cron/-/blob/master/entry.c#L485

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The valid hours range is `0-23`, so you should use

```
*/15 7-18 * * *
```

to run every 15 minutes from `07:00` (first run) to `18:45` (last run) every day.

---

The leading zero for the hour range (`07`) was the cause for the hour field to be assumed as `*`. I tested (`cronie-1.5.1-lp151.4.6.1.x86_64` on suse) that the behaviour is same to your description, for a range, like `* 01-02 * * *` but it unexpectedly worked correctly for a single value: `* 01 * * *`. So, I wouldn't dig it more, we just don't use leading zeros there.